# cross browser version of "my" scroll to top button with animation

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using a button which when clicked calls a function which scrolls to the top of the page. It is working perfectly in google chrome, but not in internet explorer. In IE, it goes to top without animation and then stops the scrolling function. I don't want this to happen. Am I making a mistake which google cannot notice and IE can???

I am not experienced with jQuery, so want a pure javascript solution.
Pleeeez try to first improve my program. If not possible, only then give a different but pure javascript solution.
Here is the program:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  if (window.scrollY != 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY - 30);
      topFunction();
    }, 5);
  }
}
```

```css
  #myBtn {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Fixed/sticky position */
  bottom: 5px;
  /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
  right: 5px;
  /* Place the button 30px from the right */
  z-index: 2;
  /* Make sure it does not overlap */
  border: none;
  /* Remove borders */
  outline: none;
  /* Remove outline */
  background-color: green;
  /* Set a background color */
  color: white;
  /* Text color */
  border-radius: 9px 9px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
  padding: 15px 20px 40px;
  height: 9px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
    nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
    anim id est laborum.</p>
  <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up custom" ></i></button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this because this will work as I am using this code to scroll the page to top using JavaScript. I have modified your code like below:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}

var x;
function topFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop!=0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop!=0){
        window.scrollBy(0,-50);
        x=setTimeout('topFunction()',10);
    }
    else clearTimeout(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in your head html5shivjs , with this library help you will be able to support html5 standart in old browsers .Simply add this cdn to your link in head script tag https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js